# How to create a vertical line with a circles above it? (with example image)

Tags: html, css

I just wonder what is the idea by HTML and CSS?
[image: QuestionImage]

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: not yet, but i'm trying now to make it with 3 divs (1 for the text, 1 for the img, 1 will be empty) using position and z-index.

Comment: try something then when you have your markup and approach we can help U...

Comment: @MODAUOD Come up with a mock up (doesn't matter how basic) on http://jsfiddle.net and post that on here 

Comment: A good way to start is to find a website that has the effect you want, right click and select  "View Page Source" or "Inspect Element". It won't always tell you exactly how to do it, but usually will give you a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You only need a css, a markup like that

```
<div class="circle-border">
    <div class="circle-image">
        <img ....>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in css

```
.circle-border{
   overflow:hidden;
   border-radius:50%;
   position:relative;
   width: 200px; //for example
   height:200px; //for example
}
.circle-image{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  border-radius:50%;
  border:8px rbba(255,255,255,.6);
 }
 .circle-border img{
    width:100%;
    object-fit:cover;
  }
```

With this you create the form, only need adjust the desing. Other and maybe simplest way is use a library like [iHover](https://github.com/gudh/ihover), that provide you the design with awesome effects, probably helpfully for what you need.

For the vertical line, is no problem. you only need make "relative" the div where you have the images and the content, after, envolve the image markup in other div and set these div with absolute position and set the "top": 50% and margin-top: with the - pixels that the size of your circle image, set the left position with the same value. The HTML may be like that:

```
<article>
<section class="container-image">
 <div class="circle-border">
    <div class="circle-image">
        <img ....>
    </div>
</div>
 <section class="content">
<!-- your content here-->
 </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh! I know this one, I did this example myself some time ago. Probably not the best solution, but i used `.class:after` (so a vertical line that goes after a circle).

Then you write the usual stuff: `content:''`; `background-color:#______`; `height`; `width`.

To put it in the center you can use the `position:relative`, `position:absolute`, `left:50%`.
You could also use css animation to do that but since it is 1 or 2 px it wouldn't make a difference.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **CSS Flexbox**. Have a look at my snippet:

```css
.timeline-holder {
  position: relative;
}

.timeline-holder:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 1px;
  height: calc(100% - 75px);
  background: #ccc;
  z-index: -1;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 60px 0;
}

.box .text {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.box img {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.box:nth-child(even) {
  margin-right: calc(50% - 75px);
}

.box:nth-child(odd) {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  margin-left: calc(50% - 75px);
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline-holder">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero amet explicabo quis expedita fuga magnam consequatur perferendis aliquam ipsum odio magni illum aperiam, quod eaque, debitis consectetur, dolorem provident quidem.</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero amet explicabo quis expedita fuga magnam consequatur perferendis aliquam ipsum odio magni illum aperiam, quod eaque, debitis consectetur, dolorem provident quidem.</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero amet explicabo quis expedita fuga magnam consequatur perferendis aliquam ipsum odio magni illum aperiam, quod eaque, debitis consectetur, dolorem provident quidem.</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero amet explicabo quis expedita fuga magnam consequatur perferendis aliquam ipsum odio magni illum aperiam, quod eaque, debitis consectetur, dolorem provident quidem.</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero amet explicabo quis expedita fuga magnam consequatur perferendis aliquam ipsum odio magni illum aperiam, quod eaque, debitis consectetur, dolorem provident quidem.</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!